# JSON Deserialization in C# for multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, json, list

I have a JSON object like this...

```
{
"totalcount":1,
"files":[
 {
"filename":"1.txt",
"fileContent":"Dineshkumar"
 }
]
}
```

I have created the following classes in C#.

```
public class File
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string fileContent { get; set; }
}

public class JSONObject
{
    public int totalcount { get; set; }
    public List<File> files { get; set; }
}
```

I have used the following objects to access the JSON object.

```
JavaScriptSerializer JSSfile = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JSSfile.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
JSONObject Content = JSSfile.Deserialize<JSONObject>(response);
```

Now my problem is.. when I have more than 1 files in the JSON object, it works perfectly fine as expected. When I have only one file in the JSON object, it returns me 0 files in `content`.

How to solve this issue?

When 1 file is given as JSON object, the Content variable values starts from 0.

If write this snippet for solving this issue,

```
if (Content.totalcount == 1)
 {
   File file = null;
   file.filename = Content.files[0].filename;
   file.fileContent = Content.files[0].fileContent;
   File.WriteAllBytes(DestLocTxt.Text.Trim() + "\\" + file.filename, file.fileContent));
  }
```

I got the following error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

 Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Problem Solved:

```
{
"totalcount":1,
"files":[
 {
"filename":"1.txt",
"fileContent":"Dineshkumar"
 }
]
}
```

was the expected JSON but the server is sending the data in different format.

```
{
"totalcount":1,
"files": {
"filename":"1.txt",
"fileContent":"Dineshkumar"
 }
}
```

All the problem caused due to this...

Comment: Could you give an example of the JSON you have with multiple files - the issue could be with this.

Comment: Validate your JSON with http://jsonlint.com/ - the example you posted is good, but I'm guessing the other one is not. If it is valid and correct, you might want to switch to [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), an all-around better JSON library.

Comment: @ScottGulliver I have updated my issue to be more clear, it is because of the list numbering and Deserialization.

Comment: @TimS. Not interested in using 3rd Party libraries, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what your issue is - is the problem that when you have more than one file in the 'files' list, then the totalcount incorrectly states 0?

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy JSON.Net does a lot of things better than the out of the box serializer.  It's pretty trivial to switch, and it's free.  It is worth investigating.

Comment: @ScottGulliver, The problem is when filecount is 1, i.e., 1 file is passed in JSONObject as mentioned above, the Contents.files[0].filename is not coming properly.

Comment: I am testing it and the json you posted at the beggining of the post works fine with your code. Could you post the json that is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is not with the JSON - it's with the File object you are creating. In the example you gave, you are trying to set the filename of file even though it is null. Ensure the object is actually instantiated before trying to set properties on it. The Content object is fine, and the files list does actually contain one file object.

This is your example, with the fix in place:

```
var json = "{\"totalcount\":1,\"files\":[{\"filename\":\"1.txt\",\"fileContent\":\"Dineshkumar\"}]}";

JavaScriptSerializer JSSfile = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JSSfile.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
JSONObject Content = JSSfile.Deserialize<JSONObject>(json);

if (Content.totalcount == 1)
{
    File file = new File(); //CREATE A NEW FILE OBJECT HERE <------
    file.filename = Content.files[0].filename;
    file.fileContent = Content.files[0].fileContent;
}
```

Comment: With this new object also same issue :(.. The problem is with the deserialization I guess.. `content` is not coming properly. :(

Comment: Strange - this example worked fine for me. Have you tried placing a breakpoint after the deserialization is done to inspect the content object?

Comment: @Scottt All this issue due to different JSON sent by the Server. Thanks a lot for helping to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your JSONObject-class like this. Than it should work:

```
public class JSONObject
{
public int totalcount { get; set; }
public File files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Files is an array so even if your code works, it will crash when he'll receive multiple files.